# I cannot see my src folder in Sources dev tools tab

Tags: reactjs

I'm using CRA on my react project. I'm trying to code split and check the sources tab but I'm not able to see the source folder. How can I enable it?

This is how it looks like:                          [image]

On the tutorial I'm watching this is what he sees: [image]